# $\lVert x-y\rVert_\infty = \frac12\lVert x-y\rVert_1$ for stochastic vectors $x, y$

Tags: probability-theory

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) on the Total Variation Distance states that for finite spaces (so, stochastic vectors), the total variation distance equals the L-infinity norm. But according to a well-known identity, the total variation distance is also equal to half the L1 norm. So we have:

$$\lVert x-y\rVert_\infty = \frac12\lVert x-y\rVert_1$$

I can't think of a counterexample right now, and if the identity is actually true and well-known then I'd rather not spend half an hour on a wild goose chase looking for one.

Comment: I highly suspect the equality. For $x = (\frac{1}{9},\frac{2}{9},\frac{3}{9},\frac{3}{9})$ and $x = (\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4})$, we have $$ \|x - y\|_{\infty} = \frac{5}{36}, \qquad \|x-y\|_1 = \frac{1}{3}. $$ On the other hand, it is always true that $\| x - y\|_{\infty} \leq \frac{1}{2}\|x - y\|_1. $ This follows from the identity $$ \|x-y\|_1 = 2\sum_i (x_i - y_i)_+ = 2\sum_i (x_i - y_i)_-. $$

Comment: @SangchulLee Well, that seems pretty conclusive to me. Some Wikipedia editor must have gotten a bit ahead of themselves.